# how do i send local storage value to server from angular

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular7

my angular .ts file is

```
       const clothsize = this.sizeForm.value.clothsize;
    const quantity = this.sizeForm.value.quantity;
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('image', file);
     formData.append('clothsize', clothsize);
     formData.append('quantity', quantity);
     formData.append('design', this.fileDesign);
     this.service.customizeAdd(formData)

}
```

service.ts file is

```
 customizeAdd(data) {
return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL}/file`, data);
```

}

I want to add local storage value of different module to that particular formdata
i have set local storage value as

```
            localStorage.setItem('user', customeruser.payload.mobilenumber);
```

i have value in local storage as

```
user : 3456788922
```

i am trying to send that user value of local storage to server with formdata above

Comment: You need to subscribe to the customizeAdd because it's returning an observable

Answer (score 0):

Since localStorage belongs to global window object, just get user value by calling anywhere in your Angular app

```
localStorage.getItem('user')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append it to formData before sending

```
formData.append('KEY', localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting your form data you can set your local storage attribute as same as other attributes.

```
formData.append('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

or you can call your server again and send it separately.

```
 customizeAdd(data) {
 return this.http.post(`url`, localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add just like-

```
  const clothsize = this.sizeForm.value.clothsize;
const quantity = this.sizeForm.value.quantity;
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('image', file);
 formData.append('clothsize', clothsize);
 formData.append('quantity', quantity);
 formData.append('design', this.fileDesign);
 formData.append('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
 this.service.customizeAdd(formData)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Retrieve the value from local storage as you normally would and append it to the `formdata`.

```
const mobile = localStorage.getItem('user');
if (mobile !== null) {
    formData.append('mobile', mobile);
}
```

2. Subscribe to your `customizeAdd()` function because it returns an Observable.

```
this.service.customizeAdd(formData).subscribe(
  response => { // handle response },
  error => { // handle error }
);
```

Even if you don't handle the response, it is always good practice to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below also:->

in angular.ts file:->

```
   formData.append('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
     this.service.customizeAdd(formData);
```

there formData contains both value.